# Phonegap filetransfer async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cordova

I have an app workflow as follows.

1) User open forms. Input data 
2) Click on add photo button, select photo. 
3) Photo gets uploaded and a new record is inserted into my db with form data and photo url.

The photo is uploaded just fine using the filetransfer method.

My codes are as follows:

I check if the variable s.photo is set.

```
if(app.isEmpty(s.photo)) {

    photo = "" ; 

}else {

    app.uploadPhoto();
    alert(s.photoresponse);

}
```

//save details here

My upload photo function is as follows:

```
uploadPhoto: function () {

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=s.photo.substr(s.photo.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    alert("uploading photo");
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(s.photo, encodeURI("http://server.com/upload.php"), app.win, app.fail, options);

}
```

And my app.win function just sets the response to s.photoresponse

```
win: function (r) {
    s.photoresponse = r.response;
}
```

If you check the first function, I tried to alert the s.photoresponse variable. Consequently even if the photo is uploaded on the server, I cannot insert the photo url to the server.

The filetransfer method is async. How can I still retrieve the photo url before submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your submit form logic to app.win function, as you say... is async, but you get response from upload in this success function.

```
win: function (r) {
    s.photoresponse = r.response;
    // Here comes your submit form logic....
    alert(s.photoresponse); //<--From your example
}
```